# Which pronoun should be used after the word ‘like’?

Tags: pronouns, formality, subjects, direct-objects

For example, which of the following is considered correct?:

> 1. Don't be like **him**
> 2. Don't be like **he** is

There are other examples I can't think of right now where people use *him* instead of *he*, or *her* instead of *she* etc.  It's frustrating!

Comment: Are you thinking of sentences such as _He is not as clever as her / she (is)_?

Comment: See also [ell.se] This **may** have already been answered there.

Comment: Please see our [help on multiple accounts](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). You need to fix the account issue so that you can edit this post.

Comment: This comes down to the *as* vs. *like* rules. Since *like* is a preposition, it takes the objective pronoun. However, if what follows is a clause, then *as* is appropriate, not *like*. The second example should have *as*.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct because ***LIKE*** can be both  a preposition ('like him') and a conjunction ('like he is').

After the preposition  we should use the object pronoun (him, her, me, us, them).

After the conjunction we should use the subject pronoun (he, she, I, we, they) which is followed by the personal verb form.

See Merriam-Webster's Dictionary 
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like):

***LIKE***

*Conjunction*

: in the same way that

: AS

// they raven down scenery like children do sweetmeats

— John Keats

*Preposition*

: typical of

// was like him to do that

Comment: Hmm... See answer by BillJ.

Comment: Dictionaries are wrong about this. "Like" is neither a preposition nor a conjunction, but an adjective in the OP's examples.

Comment: I'd have trouble believing some random user over an authoritative source like American Heritage Dictionary.

Comment: @BlackandWhite FYI. My grammar is based entirely on that of the award-winning _Cambridge Grammar of The English Language_ (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002). Huddleston is the finest grammarian of English alive today. Dictionaries should never be used for matters of grammar.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *Don't be like him*.
>
> [2] *Don't be like he is*.

"Like" is an adjective in both your examples. The difference between them is that in [1] the pronoun is direct complement of "like", and since adjectives take accusative case pronouns as complement, it must be "him".

But in [2], the pronoun is subject of a finite comparative clause, and since finite clauses take nominative case subjects, it must be "he".

Comment: Hmm... See answer by user307254.

Comment: If *like* is an adjective in *don't be like him*, why isn't *over* an adjective in *I'm not over him*? I'd call them both prepositions.

Comment: This is completely wrong. In the first example, *like* is a preposition. The second example is a common grammatical error in which people use *like* when they should use *as*.

Comment: @BlackandWhite Nonsense. In [1] "like" is in predicative complement function. Unlike prepositions, but like many adjectives, "like" freely accepts modification by "very", as in "Ed is very like his father", and sometimes by "too". And unlike preps, adjectival "like" is related to a predicand in the same way that other predicative AdjPs are. Further, "like" is one of only four transitive adjectives -- the ones that license NP complements. As far as "as" is concerned, it may be in competition with "like", but in no way is it preferable. The prep "like", by contrast, occurs as head of an adjunct.